# Android context not getting the right localization resource

Tags: android

Description: I have an app that adds saves and displays **Activity** objects, and displays a `Toast` message on doing so. I also have two languages that the program operates with, for which resource files have been provided.

Problem: Translation works perfectly for all UI elements, except the `Toast` messages that I display on success. I'm giving it an application context, but if I switch the language, it will end up displaying the `Toast` in the other language, while the other UI is using the proper language. The resources don't contain the same `string` for both languages. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a section of the **Activity** saving code:

```
 private void uploadActivities(FirebaseFirestore db, ArrayList<ActivityModel> activities) {
        for (int i = 0; i < allRecurringActivities.size(); i++) {
            db.collection("Project").document(Prefs.getString("iD",
                    GlobalObject.FIRESTORE_ID))
                    .collection("activities")
                    .document(activities.get(i).getId())
                    .set(activities.get(i))
                    .addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "" +
                                context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.success) +
                                "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        for (ActivityModel allRecurringActivity : allRecurringActivities) {
                            AlarmUtils.setAlarm(context, allRecurringActivity);
                        }
                            }
                    )
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.d("uploadActivities", "FAILED"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `Activity` as a `Context` for user-facing elements such as strings, not `Application`.

Many resource-overriding mechanisms such as in-app language switchers work by updating the resources in the `Activity`. Other `Context`s are not updated. It's not evident in the question that you are using in-app language switching (though that would explain the behavior) - without that an `Application` also would access the same resources. But generally, `Activity` is the right context to use for user interfaces.